# How to put Tensor objects in the same graph?

Tags: python, ajax, django, tensorflow

I'm trying to create a web-based machine learning application using Django and TensorFlow. In the views.py (server side), I have created several placeholders and operations and save them globally within the views.py. The view then displays (renders) an HTML file called train.html. In it, I call another function in views.py using AJAX, to run the operations I have created previously, but it comes out with the error:

> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Tensor Tensor("input:0", shape=(?, 9, 44), dtype=int32) is not an element of this graph.

Here's an over-simplification of my code (without specifying imports, as it's obviously not an import problem):

**views.py**

```
# Create TF placeholders and operations
input = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 9, 44], name='input')
operation_1 = tf.reduce_mean(input)


def index(request):
    render('my_app/train.html')  # Displays train.html page


def perform_operation(request):
    global input, operation_1
    sess.run(operation_1, {input: request.POST['input']})
    return HttpResponse(1)
```

**train.html**

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'perform_operation' %}"  # Calls perform_operation method in views.py,
        data: {"input": [1, 2, 3]}
    });
</script>
```

The error I specified previously points to the "sess.run" line.

I've been searching the solution for this all day long, and still nothing comes to light.
Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Wrapping the Tensor objects with `graph.as_default()` does it. The `graph` is initialized with `graph = tf.Graph()` and is saved globally.